# Wordpress 4.4.2 upload give error, can't write is upper directory allowed to be written

Tags: images, uploads

I searched around for this problem en found a lot of ideas most has to do with write access. The idea is: Put all directories in the wp-content/upload to 744 if not work to 755 and all the files to 644 (like this one for example: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-image-upload-issue-in-wordpress/). And some even said 777 looks to me a bit of a over kill but, I tried and it didn't work as well. I keep getting the some error.

Empty cash of browser and from Wordpress it self. Didn't do the trick.

The rights to the directories is to the user and the root so I would say the the system has all access to the directory. I have ssh access to change if needed.

Even if i write a small code to copy a image from a uploaded image. It made a new directory in wp-content/upload and it did copy the file. But when i try it with Wordpress it still fails.

Does anyone has a idea of what I can try more?

Answer (score 0):

Okay seems that after a migration your media point not to the right directories. So don't be so stupid as me and check all so at **settings**->**media** if the directory is correct. Sometimes the solution is so simple and you think too hard for a difficult solution.